# New angular dart project fails to start from IntelliJ

Tags: angular-dart

I created a new Angular Dart project from IntelliJ but when I try to run the project I get the following output:

```
/usr/local/opt/dart/libexec/bin/pub global run webdev serve web:61889
No active package webdev.
Dart Dev Server terminated
```

Is there something I still need to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to run

```
pub global activate webdev
```

as mentioned in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webdev

[image]

Comment: Im getting the same error, and I have run `pub global activate webdev`.

Comment: Can't imagine.What happens when you run `pub global run webdev serve` from command line in the project directory?

Comment: As an addition to answer. 
If you cannot run project after `pub global activate webdev` you need to manually run `pub global run webdev serve web:53322`
It worked for me.